# Recomputing Spark Partition all the way from the initial source due to Node failure and changed data at source

Tags: apache-spark

I cannot simulate this, so a quick check on a non-Streaming situation, just DF or RDD regular processing:

- If a Spark Worker Node fails

  - and thus a given RDD computation/computations is/are lost

    - and there is no caching, checkpointing, etc. applied,

      - then for the recompute,

        - how does this pan out if the data at source has changed and it could mean that in fact the other Nodes would need some extra data due to re-partitioning?
        - what does it mean in terms of performance of the initial read that may have been a lot of data followed by a repartition?

I.e. we are talking about non-deterministic situation here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** - If we consider a source like `JDBC`, the query would be executed[1] against the DB during re-compute. If the records change it would lead to skewed results. I don't think the job would fail.

[1] - This is based on [JdbcRDD](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/JdbcRDD.scala#L78-L110) code.

---

Regarding your first question, Spark's partitions are very similar (in fact built out of Hadoop's InputSplit from InputFormat). Each [FileSplit](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/ac0538aac347bfd97cc0dee1db49db503c15f1d9/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileSplit.java#L42-L44) generally contains the following properties

- InputPath
- StartOffset
- Length (generally block size on the cluster)

So let's consider the following cases when you say the data at the source has changed

```
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|         Scenario         |                        What happens                         |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| New file get's added     | The new files are not part of the input splits              |
|                          | so they're not captured as part of the partitions.          |
| Existing file is deleted | This will cause the job to fail with FileNotFoundException. |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Regarding your second question, When you say repartition there're again two ways. With `shuffling=true` and without.

Without shuffling it's is really just bunching a list of InputSplits together into a single partition (if new `numPartitions` < existing partitions). In case of re-evaluation they would be read again from the source.

If you had `shuffling=true` during repartition, the spark does book keeping required to find the missing partitions and re-run the tasks. You can read more about that [in here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-scheduler-ShuffleMapStage.html). So the same situation as above applies while re-reading the partitions from the input.

PS: I've assumed the source is a Hadoop compatible Filesystem.

Comment: The source may be 1) JDBC and the 2) underlying Hadoop data may have been sqooped and changed in a delta process on Hive. How would that work? Indeed WORM does apply but we see more and more of this type of thing. I think I diod not phrase the question well enough as I was looking for non-deterministic outcome.

Comment: I'm aware of the points you make in general, just to be clear.

Comment: It sounds to me it will fail, but it was about non deterministic.

Comment: What about a JOIN on Hive with another Hive table on the first sql query? Could give a different result with a where clause...

Comment: I've added a note about JDBC source. My point being it wouldn't be a failure, it might almost skew the results.

Comment: Thinking vs knowing. It could be that the JDBC source data may lead to a wide-transformation due to new results potentially - as it were - in that some result may not fit in that task processing for the given original partition. Not sure what to make of the update. I am not sure I can simulate this myself.

Comment: But I agree it's hard to simulate.

Comment: So we cannot say we know the answer. Either the newer data is discarded or there is a failure, or both could be a possibility.

Comment: I can in my own mind see how I would implement this. Results would be both discarded and included based on numPartitions and such but it would not need to fail. Not sure I get the update but will award the answer as I do not think it would fail either.

Comment: For Hdfs you have valid points but newer files added in search path would be excluded imho.